# MAX and COUNT sql query

Tags: php, sql

I need to know how to use `MAX()` and `COUNT()` query to display the "fiser" table entries that contain the primary "codp" key that comes from the "products" table, depending on a previously selected period?

Table **products** : *codp*, denp ;

Table **orders**: *codc*,*codp* ;

Table **returns** : *codr*, datar, *codc*, *codp*

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $sql = "SELECT p.denp, a.datar,MAX(p.codp) 
            FROM ( SELECT COUNT(p.codp) FROM products p ) products p
                INNER JOIN orders o ON p.codp=o.codp
                INNER JOIN returns r ON o.codc=r.codc 
            WHERE  r.datar>=STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['d1']."','%Y-%m-%d') 
            AND r.datar<=STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['d2']."','%Y-%m-%d')  ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($queryResult > 0 ){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo "
                <table border=1 >
                <tr>
                    <td><p> ".$row['codp']." </p></td>
                    <td><p> ".$row['denp']." </p></td> 
                    <td><p> " .$row['codr']." </p></td>
                    <td><p> " .$row['datar']." </p></td>
                    <td><p> " .$row['codc']." </p></td>
                </tr> </table> ";
        }   

    } else { 
        echo " No results!" ;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to sql injection in the d1 and d2 parameter

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Your query doesn't even run.  Fix your query properly.  Where's the `GROUP BY`????

Answer (score 1):

You should use group by for codp and the join the related  result eg:

```
$sql = "SELECT p.denp, r.datar,MAX(p.cnt_codp) 
    FROM ( 
          SELECT codp, COUNT(*)  as cnt_codp FROM products  
          group by codp
    ) products p
    INNER JOIN orders o ON p.codp=o.codp
    INNER JOIN returns r ON o.codc=r.codc 
  WHERE  r.datar>=STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['d1']."','%Y-%m-%d') 
      AND r.datar<=STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['d2']."','%Y-%m-%d')  
   GROUP BY p.denp, r.datar ";
```

and you should check for your db driver for param bindig instead of use of php var in sql (you are at risk for sql injection)

and you should also use a group by for not aggreated  column  or reeval the question if you need  the values related  to max result   (the use of aggregation function without a proper group by columns for not aggreagated  is depreacted  in sql ai the most recent version of mysql is not allowed)

Comment: You missed the `a.datar` I dont see the OP assigning an `a` alias anywhere, or an I missing something

Comment: No problem, my pleasure

Comment: Thank you. Yes, should be r.datar.